# I don't want to Re-authenticate a user if he change password for his account in firebase email password authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

As per firebase documentation changing a password—require that the user has recently signed in.
But in my case user has signed with same login credentials on multiple devices(e.g. 50) and when he reset password for his account user get logout from all devices.
I don't want them to logout from all devices, is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to configure what you want in Firebase's built in email+password provider. You *could* build your own provider that works the way you describe, but I'd recommend against it.

The main reason for changing the password of an account is to counter the risk that the account/password was compromised. If you allow the user to change the password on one device, but to continue using the account on other devices without entering the new password, a malicious user can continue to use the compromised credentials on those other devices.